# Change width of canvas using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using [this](https://codepen.io/kunukn/pen/kkbNvx) JavaScript signature pad that I found in code pen. I can set the width of the canvas using HTML

```
<canvas id="signature-pad" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

I can change the width as much as I want. However, when I change the width using CSS like `width:80vw` even though the canvas width increases I can either no longer sign in there or the mouse pointer and the pointer for the signature is at a different place. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: How about using js to resize canvas on window resize event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add something like this to the constructor of your SignaturePad ([codepen fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYgPJE)):

```
    canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
      canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;
    });
```

The calculations of the mouse position only work correctly if your canvas drawing width and height is equal to the canvas element width and height.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

`width` and `height` attributes on `canvas` element specify the amount of pixels you can draw on. By using CSS to make your canvas bigger you just stretch your `600x200` canvas to make it *appear* bigger.

**How to fix this?**

Use `height` and `width` attributes to resize your canvas the way you expect - with JavaScript, for example on `resize` event.